# Detecting Periodic Billiard Orbits

Tags: geometry

I've been thinking about the [triangular billiard problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344053/why-is-the-billiard-problem-for-obtuse-triangles-so-hard), which asks

> Does every triangle contain a periodic billiard orbit?

I have created a simulation to experiment with this problem. In my simulation, one can manipulate the initial conditions of the ball (position and velocity $P_0, V_0$) and triangle (angles $\alpha, \beta$). My goal now is to implement some sort of algorithm that will detect periodic orbits in the simulation. Here are some results from my simulation:

[image]

I am aware of [Schwartz's (2008) unfolding algorithm](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-18/issue-2/Obtuse-Triangular-Billiards-II--One-Hundred-Degrees-Worth-of/em/1259158426.full) which reflects the triangle instead of the path. However, I was considering if there are easier alternatives which may be simpler to programmatically implement.

In particular, I was wondering whether imposing some conservative vector field $\nabla{F}$ in which $W=\int{F \cdot dr}=0$ for a loop would be an effective detector of periodic paths. If not, why would this fail and what would be some alternative means of detecting periodic orbits?

I should note that I have previously asked how a simulation can be used to [computationally reproduce Schwartz's (2009) proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352812/using-a-simulation-to-show-that-any-obtuse-triangle-whose-largest-angle-is-leq). The answer to that question and further experimentation helped me extensively understand the unfolding algorithm, but due to the computational complexity of implementing such a method, I'm now considering if there are any alternatives.

Comment: "*detect periodic orbits in the simulation*" $\;-\;$ You should clarify whether the question is about periodicity vs. simulation. Numerical calculations will always have precision limits which can cause both false negatives and false positives.

Comment: Hi @dxiv. I am concerned primarily with an algorithm which will enable me to detect periodic paths within a certain degree of accuracy, not withstanding round-off errors, precision limits, etc. I am already aware of the unfolding algorithm, but I'm asking here for some feedback on an idea I mention above or other alternatives.

Comment: You should mention your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4352812/305862) with its interesting answer and comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JeanMarie. I've added a brief summary of them at the end.